# how to retrive the value of variables outside dynamic pl-sql?

Tags: plsql, dynamic-sql, execute-immediate

I perform the following query:

```
declare 
  i number;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(1) from someTable' returning into i;
  dbms_output.put_line(i);
end;
```

and get this Error: returning clause must be used with insert, update and delete!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using bind variables with dynamic SELECT INTO clause in PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816402/using-bind-variables-with-dynamic-select-into-clause-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Just a small syntax error (no RETURNING):

```
DECLARE
    i NUMBER;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from user_tables' INTO i;
    dbms_output.put_line(i);
END;
```